# how to bind xml file in listbox?

Tags: wpf, xml, listbox, bind

I have an xml file as shown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PhoneBook xmlns="http://tempuri.org/PhoneBook.xsd">
<Person>
<PersonItem name="name1" famil="famil1">
  <Numbers>
    <NumbersItem number="123456" />
    <NumbersItem number="789100" />
  </Numbers>
</PersonItem>
</Person>
<Person>
<PersonItem name="name2" famil="famil2">
  <Numbers>
    <NumbersItem number="654321" />
    <NumbersItem number="111213" />
  </Numbers>
</PersonItem>
</Person>
</PhoneBook>
```

I have successfully bound a listbox to this XML using the following:

```
Imports <xmlns:DaftarTelephone="http://tempuri.org/PhoneBook.xsd">

   Dim xmlPhoneBook = XDocument.Load(CurDir() & "\PhoneBook.xml")
   Dim q = From el In xmlPhoneBook ...<PhoneBook:PersonItem>
   lst.ItemsSource = q        'my listbox
```

Here's my XAML:

```
    <Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PersonItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[famil].Value}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[name].Value}"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Attribute[number].Value}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</Page.Resources>

<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot"  >
    <ListBox x:Name="lst" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource PersonItemTemplate}" />
       </Grid>
```

family and name is shown correctly. But numbers are not shown!!!

Comment: As far as I can see... you have a collection of numbers, but you are using it as a single element.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ;how to show first attribute collection in collection?

Comment: Not quite sure, but try this: ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Attributes[Number].Value

Comment: What kind of objects are you getting when load that data? XmlNode?

Comment: I'm using xpath.And working properly